Max x/y values for viewbox to prevent zooming / panning outside
I am implementing a custom zoom/pan in JS with viewbox. When the x, y, width and height for the new viewbox have been calculated, i want to set them. Before setting them, i want to check them to be between 0 and max, where max is the value to make sure, that the svg content after zooming / panning is not "outside", does not leave weird wite blanks on the screen because somebody moved to far out.
I am currently failing at calculating that max value. My code is:
function setViewbox(x, y, width, height) {
    var xMax = baseWidth - container.offsetWidth / getXZoom()
    var yMax = baseHeight - container.offsetHeight / getYZoom()

    ... make sure xy is between 0 and xMax/yMax ...

    svgElement.viewbox(x, y, width, height)
}

baseWidth is the complete width of the svg element / the viewport.
container.offsetWidth is the width of the container displaying the svgElement (shorter on both axis than the svg child element).
My idea is, that my max viewbox x value should be the width of the svgElement minus whatever can be displayed on the container element, keeping zoom in mind.
However, that does not work and calculates just wrong values. Any idea where i am going wrong?

shouldn't you need some calc getBBox in there? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman The values that are passed into setViewbox() are already calculated correctly, meaning something like getBBox() is already factored in. In this case, i was using the typical point.matrixTransform(svgElement.node.getScreenCTM().inverse()) to get the actual click position in the svg.
